# Android 2.1 - MyTouch 3G Slide - Preparing SD Card mal-function - Formatted SD Card after taking out and putting back in :(

Tags: external-sd, 2.1-eclair, htc-mytouch-3g-slide

Operating System: Android 2.2
Device: HTC MyTouch 3G Slide 
SD Card: Micro SD 8GB Sandisk card that is less than 1 year old

Background: 
This feature formatted my working SD Card w/ all my pictures on it after i took it out and put it back into the same phone. I didn't add or delete any data from the device when i took it out... I checked the sd card on the computer and it only had 2mb of cache files on it while before it had 6gb of music and photos. I already tried mounting and unmounting the card. That doesn't help. The phone has recently been factory restored.

Questions: 
1) Why is Android / MyTouch3G Slide formatting my sd card?

2) How do I know if it's an sd card problem or a phone problem?

3) How do I get the card to work w/ the pictures and mp3s on there?

I'm thinking maybe I should prepare the card for android somehow- with a sd card formatter

Update:  I recovered the files w Easeus Data Recovery, put them back on the card, and it formatted the files again. I'm thinking I should format my card for android 2.2 or mytouch3g so it accepts the pictures or put the card in while the phone is off to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: For trying to get back data try http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: did you check the card on a PC to see if the files were still there? or did you just try to access the photos from the phone. I haven't experienced this before but if the sd card wasn't mounted maybe the photos appeared to be missing but weren't. or did you actually get a message that said the card was formatted? just a thought...

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for the response! Yes, I checked for files on pc and nothing. I tried mounting and unmounting card. I added more info to my question so it's more clear. Check it out and let me know... thanks!

Comment: @AdoPilot, thanks, I recovered the files w Easeus Data Recovery. The question is once I recovered the files, is there a file system structure I have to keep on there or other way to prepare the sd card so the phone doesnt have to "prepare"/ format it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My buddy with a HTC Evo 4G w/ Android 2.2 put the SD Card in his phone and had no problem reading the files on the SD Card. The files were on a seperate partition that wasn't recognized w/ my myTouchSlide using 2.1. He was unable to format the card with his Evo but had a card adapter and put it in his computer and formatted the card on his computer. :)

He said Best Practices are:

- Un-mounting the SD card before you remove it from the phone
- Putting the card back in when the phone is off
- Backing up your SD card data regularly just in case

Answer (score 1):

Android has to mount your SD card; that's all that "Preparing SD Card" does.  If that doesn't happen, then the device can't use the SD card.  Hopefully the format was just a fluke.  You should put test files on it (unimportant / already backed up) and see if it happens again.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes, I recovered the files w Easeus Data Recovery, put them back on the card, and it formatted it again. I'm thinking I should format my card for android 2.2 or mytouch3g so it accepts the pictures or put the card in while the phone is off to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: That's very strange.  Maybe try a different card and see if the same thing happens.  And I agree that removing/inserting the card while the phone is off is good to try.